# Nikon D810 reset my file numbers

Tags: nikon, file

Recently, I downloaded images from the SD card on my Nikon D810 that had numbers from DSC7042 to DSC7107 because I needed some images right away.  I then put the card back into the camera (NO re-formatting or changing settings in any menu) and continued shooting.  At the end of the shoot, the camera had re-numbered all the pictures from DSC0361 to DSC0652.  In other words, the former DSC7042 was now DSC0361.  How can I restore the camera's numbering and (ii) how can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: To be clear - you are claiming the camera renamed the existing photos on the card to new numbers?!

Comment: Related:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/72247/6508

Comment: @rrauenza  He is claiming just that:  "In other words, the former DSC7042 was now DSC0361"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [question](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2556/%7E/image-file-name%2F-numbering-sequence) at Nikon.

It talks about Custom Settings Menu d6:

> By default sequential numbering is set to "OFF"
>
> Sequential file numbering OFF - When a new card is inserted the current folder and file numbers are not continued, file numbering starts again in a new folder.
>
> Sequential file numbering ON - When a new card is inserted the camera can continue numbering files in sequence from the last file number on the previous card.

Comment: Thank you, Rrauenza.  My sequential file numbering was always set to ON.  As I state in my question, I did not change any settings in the menu.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood.  You are claiming the camera renamed the existing photos on the card?!